# Access iframe's "unnamed" parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parent

If I had some thing like this:

```
<div id="parent">
<iframe....></iframe>
</div>
```

I could: window.parent.document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML. But I have something like this:

```
<div>
<iframe....></iframe>
</div>
```

Is there anyway of accessing this? I might have anywhere up to 20 iframes on a given page, and would prefer not to make 20 individual iframe pages.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.frameElement` is a reference to the IFRAME element containing the current page. You can use `window.frameElement.parentNode` (inside of the IFRAME) to get the unnamed parent element.

Be aware that the property is non-standard. `frameElement` *seems* to be supported in Firefox, Opera, and IE.

Answer (score 1):

so im assuming you control the the parents code

then you can iterate true all the iframes and give them a reference to the parent
div to use.

Comment: Good idea, I was thinking of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you: `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")`.

[W3School's Page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp)

This method will return a vector with all elements with tag it found in the page.

Comment: I think you meant `getElementsByTagName`