# jquery selection from iframe to div on mail page

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors

How can I modify content from a script on a iframe to the main body, something like this:

```
$("window#text").text("main body DIV modified!");
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066271/access-iframes-unnamed-parent also, be weary of xss restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to visit [How to access parent.document elements using JQuery in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133276/how-to-access-parent-document-elements-using-jquery-in-firefox) - there's a lot of good answers about accessing elements from parent frames using jQuery.